# How to parse multiple json by jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I know how to use jquery to parase simple json.

json

```
 {
        "Symbol": "AAL.L",
        "Name": "ANGLO AMERICAN",
        "Last": "3061.50",
        "Date": "7/26/2011",
        "Time": "11:35am",
        "Change": "+35.00(+1.16%)",
        "High": "3087.00",
        "Low": "3047.00",
        "Volume": "3160820",
        "Bid": "3061.50",
        "Ask": "3062.50",
        "PercentChange": "+1.16%"
    }
```

jquery

```
 $.getJSON("1.json", function(data) {
                    $("div").html("<p>Symbol="+data.Symbol+" Time="+data.Time+" Bid="+data.Bid+"</p>");
             });
```

But, now I have a json file like:

```
[
    {
        "Symbol": "AAL.L",
        "Name": "ANGLO AMERICAN",
        "Last": "3061.50",
        "Date": "7/26/2011",
        "Time": "11:35am",
        "Change": "+35.00(+1.16%)",
        "High": "3087.00",
        "Low": "3047.00",
        "Volume": "3160820",
        "Bid": "3061.50",
        "Ask": "3062.50",
        "PercentChange": "+1.16%"
    },
    {
        "Symbol": "AAL.L",
        "Name": "ANGLO AMERICAN",
        "Last": "3061.50",
        "Date": "7/26/2011",
        "Time": "11:35am",
        "Change": "+35.00(+1.16%)",
        "High": "3087.00",
        "Low": "3047.00",
        "Volume": "3160820",
        "Bid": "3061.50",
        "Ask": "3062.50",
        "PercentChange": "+1.16%"
    },
    {
        "Symbol": "AAL.L",
        "Name": "ANGLO AMERICAN",
        "Last": "3061.50",
        "Date": "7/26/2011",
        "Time": "11:35am",
        "Change": "+35.00(+1.16%)",
        "High": "3087.00",
        "Low": "3047.00",
        "Volume": "3160820",
        "Bid": "3061.50",
        "Ask": "3062.50",
        "PercentChange": "+1.16%"
    }
]
```

I can't use that way to parase. the result is "undefined".
How can I parase this. Additionly, I want the result is like:

```
Symbol = [num, num, num], Time = [num, num, num], Bid = [num, num, num]
```

Could someone tell me how to do that. 
Many thanks!!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$.getJSON("1.json", function(data) {
    var i = 0, dataSize = data.length, html = '';

    for(i; i < dataSize; i++){
        html += "<p>Symbol="+data[i].Symbol+" Time="+data[i].Time+" Bid="+data[i].Bid+"</p>";
    }

    $("div").html(html);
});
```

#### Edit

Based on @Robert Koritnik's comment, "*instead of a single object* [...] [you] *got back an array of objects that* [...] [you] *have to access*."

Comment: You should explain a little why this works, because OP is obviously not as seasoned with Javascript and JSON. Maybe they don't know that instead of a single object they got back an array of objects that they have to access.

Comment: @Robert Koritnik: It works, because JavaScript just works. There are merely five core lines of code to wrap the head around. The OP didn't ask why his version is not working, it was already obvious, a solution was sought to adjust for the new object. I will add your suggestion, just to make you happy.

Answer (score 1):

`[]` means array so you need to access the items by key like `data[0]`. you can loop over them with for or `$.each()`.

```
$.getJSON("1.json", function(data) {
  $.each(data, function(i,obj){
    $("div").html("<p>Symbol="+obj.Symbol+" Time="+obj.Time+" Bid="+obj.Bid+"</p>");
  });                    
});
```

If you want the result restructured then youd have to loop over it in the same fashion and create a new structure. ID give an example but i dont understand where you are going ith `[num,num,num]`....

Comment: It's so bad performance-wise to change the DOM for every iteration. Also, `$.each` is way slower than the native `for` loop.

Comment: @Shef: *Slower* may be... But decision which one to use should not entirely rely on speed alone.

Comment: @shef: I agree with you on the DOM manipulation on every iteration... but as far as `$.each` there more to it than performance. IF raw prformance was the only concern then no on would use jquery or another lib at all.

Comment: @Robert Koritnik: Yes, it is slower, and I don't see any advantage here on using the `$.each`. If you do, please, enlighten me!

Comment: @prodigitalson: Using jQuery is one thing, overusing it is totally another one. jQuery is the Swiss army knife of DOM manipulation, don't abuse it.

Answer (score 0):

Just use an iterator

```
 data[0].Symbol
```

etc.